# Bootstrap set column full width if its the only column in a row

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

**POST UPDATED:**

in my web all and some page i'm using `col-xx-xx` to divide posts to single column such as `col-md-6`, when i use this option to divide posts next column maybe empty for example:

all columns as `col-md-6` are in one `row`, not two column in one row

[image]

now my question is: how can i fill this row have only one column as `col-md-6` or how can i set `col-md-12` class to `div` to fill that in current row?

pesudo code:

```
<div class="row" style="padding: 20px;">
    <?php
    $row = 1;
    $col = 6;
    ?>
    @foreach ($webDevelopmentArticles as $articles)
        @foreach ($articles as $article)
            <?php
            if ($row % 2 == 0)
                $col = 6;
            else
                $col = 12;
            $row ++;
            ?>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-{{$col}} col-lg-{{$col}} pull-right">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

offset comes to the rescue for your problem. `col-md-offset-6`

**UPDATE:**
Now that fully understood your question, you need a logic which checks if the row is going to be the last one and if it is, we need to check if its an odd row so it will be on `col-md-12`. Here is the code:

```
<?php
       @foreach ($articles as $index => $article)
            // if its the last row and its odd number
            if ($index % 2 == 0 && count($articles) === ($index+1))
                $col = 12;
            else
                $col = 6;
            ?>
```

This code is untested and I haven't coded in PHP for a while. But I believe this should work.

Comment: don't work correctly and i have empty column for all rows

Comment: Did you add col-md-6 with it? like `col-md-6 col-md-offset-6`

Comment: I'm so sorry I made a mistake to describe about my problem, my post updated, thanks in advance

Comment: Just to clarify your question... Do you want to put the last column as full width if the number  of divs you want to show are odd? i.e. if you have 5 divs, 2 rows of col-md-6 and last row as col-md-12?

Comment: then you need some more logic. if `webDevelopmentArticles.length === $index+1` (if this is the last item in the loop) then add the second logic ` if ($row % 2 == 0)`

Comment: I updated my answer. I removed your $row variable. let me know how this goes

Comment: with latest solution all columns are `col-md-12`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174601/discussion-between-matthew-barbara-and-doldurma).

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have a 2-dimensional array in this case which looks like the following.

```
<?PHP
   $webDevelopmentArticles = 
   Array(
         'row1'=>array('article1','article2'),
         'row2'=>array('article3')
   );
?>
```

So the article should fill up the full row instead of sharing it. The assumption is also that each nested array is on a max length of 2.

Then the code I would write will look something like this

```
<?PHP foreach ($webDevelopmentArticles as $articles):
     $col=6;
     if(count($articles)==1){
        $col=12;
     } 
  ?>
   <div class="row" style="padding: 20px;">
     <?PHP foreach ($articles as $article):?>
        <div class="col-md-<?PHP echo $col?>">
          <?PHP echo $article;?>
        </div>
     <?PHP endforeach;?>
   </div>
<?PHP endforeach;?>
```