# Having issue displaying div to full width on a page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, sass

I am trying to display divs side by side on a page. However, if there is only one `col-md-6` div class on the page, then I am trying to display it full width(100%) rather than 50%. Currently it's using only 50% even if there is only one `col-md-6`. Is there a way to do this using CSS?
Here is the my HTML and CSS:

```
   <div class="col-md-6 textcontent">
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-6 service">
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-6 textcontent">
   </div>
```

CSS

```
.col-md-6{
width50%;
}
```

Comment: This is very broad but the idea could be `if ($('.col-md-6').length == 1) {$('.col-md-6').toggleClass("col-md-6 col-md-12")}`

Comment: I don't know if the html is generated by maybe something like mvc or php but then this can also be a solution `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51233765/bootstrap-set-column-full-width-if-its-the-only-column-in-a-row/51233888`

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox is the way to go here. Here is an example:

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* For display purposes */
  padding: 1rem;
}

.pink {
  background-color: pink;
}

.blue {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.green {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.orange {
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrap">
  <div class="item pink">
    Content 1
  </div>
  <div class="item blue">
    Content 2
  </div>
  <div class="item green">
    Content 3
  </div>
</section>

<section class="wrap">
  <div class="item orange">
    Content Solo
  </div>
</section>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/willihyde/aqrs410u/1/

Comment: This is easiest with flex layout, but a combination of `display: grid` and `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 1fr)` could potentially achieve the same. To be clear: this isn't a criticism of your (great) answer, but a suggestion if you wanted to expand your answer.

Comment: @DavidThomas Is 100% right here. Grid is also an excellent solution and worth mentioning. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the bootstrap, You can use the col-md-12 class to add a full width column. bootstrap grid system is coming as a fraction system and your number will be divide by 12. So if we divide the 6 by 12 the answer is 0.5 and that means 50%. That's why it's adding a 50% width column. So when we add 12 it will divide by 12/12 and the width will be 100%. You can follow the [Bootstrap grid system guideline](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/) to learn more about the various width ratios and how to make a responsive grid.

```
<div class="col-md-12 service"></div>
```

If you are trying to build this by yourself, Define another class with a name and add the width: 100%;

```
.col-md-12{
   width:100%;
}
```

Then add that class name to your html class attribute

```
<div class="col-md-12 service"></div>
```